# ORA2PG -unable to read packages

Tags: ora2pg

My Ora2pg is able to migrate tables and views from  Oracle to PGSQL.
But,however unable to read packages.Its showing as

```
ora2pg -p -t PACKAGE -o package.sql -b c:\ora2pg\appln -c c:\ora2pg\ora2pg_appln.conf
[========================>] 0/0 packages (100.0%) end of output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out,necessary permission to execute the package for the user was not there...necessary permission given to user,it worked.